# How to create custom field in ubercart 3.x checkout page?

Tags: ubercart

I want to customize checkout page and remove/add some fields from client information.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Extra Fields Checkout Pane](http://drupal.org/project/uc_extra_fields_pane) module.

> This module allows an administrator to define additional (billing and shipping) address fields as well as custom order fields in Ubercart e-commerce suite. These fields will be available during checkout process and in order handling pages.
>   This module has been developed and tested with Ubercart 2.6.
>
> [image: screenshot]